# draft.js: how to preserve paragraph breaks when pasting content?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Is there documentation that explains how to preserve paragraph breaks when content is pasted into draft.js?  Other formating looks reasonable but all the paragraph blocks are collapsed into a single paragraph block when pasting.

Comment: try https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-import-html, which help you import html.

Comment: No, draft-js-import-html is no help in this case. (I use draft-js-import-html already to convert HTML to editorState for loading content -- works fine). But that's no help when _pasting_ content from another app:  _all the paragraph separators get stripped out._

Comment: pasting html string or plain text?

Comment: _Not_ plain text, but text copied to the clip board from any other application that uses rich text. Pasting such text into TInyMCE, Quil, CKEditor, etc. all preserve both inline formatting and paragraphs.  Pasting into draft.js removes the line breaks, so that the entire pasted text is a single paragraph.

Comment: draft only process plain text or html.

Comment: "draft only process plain text or html" -- Actually this is _incorrect_. Draft.js itself processes neither. It has it's own internal format (read the docs), but one may convert other formats (plain text, HTML, RTF, or whatever) to the internal format.  The problem here is there is no obvious method to intercept a paste and do the translation before the pasted text is inserted.

Comment: yes I mean 'process pasting plain text or html' actually.

Comment: I believe it was a design decision. If you copy a big block of text from another editor, it's probably going to insert a newline after each line of text in the paragraph. So instead, they parse them out. https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/231

Comment: @SteveB Did you ever figure out how to preserve paragraphs? I'm trying to do that in react-rte - https://github.com/sstur/react-rte

Answer (score 7):

You can handle this using a prop for Editor.

```js
handlePastedText = (text: string, html?: string, editorState: EditorState) => {
    const selection = editorState.getSelection();
    const pastedBlocks = ContentState.createFromText(text).blockMap;
    const newState = Modifier.replaceWithFragment(
        editorState.getCurrentContent(),
        editorState.getSelection(),
        pastedBlocks,
    );
    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newState, "insert-fragment");
    this.handleChange(newEditorState);
    return "handled";
};
```

And then pass this as props in Editor. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no public documentation of processing of pasted content. But since draft-js is open-sourced, reading the sources comes to the rescue.

**Draft-js 0.9.1 and below**

Just specify `p` as aliased element for `unstyled` block using [blockRenderMap](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map.html#configuring-block-render-map):

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import Editor from 'draft-js';

const customRenderMap = Map({
  unstyled: {
    element: 'div',
    // will be used in convertFromHTMLtoContentBlocks
    aliasedElements: ['p'],
  },
});

<Editor
  editorState={this.state.editorState}
  blockRenderMap={customRenderMap}
/>
```

**Explanation:**

When you paste content to draft-js, [editOnPaste](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/src/component/handlers/edit/editOnPaste.js) function gets invoked. Inside it draft determines that content you pasted is html (yes, when you copy-paste any text from text processors like MS Word, Google Docs or Apple Pages, it's actually html), and calls [convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks()](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/src/model/encoding/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js).

`convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks()` in its turn [uses blockRenderMap](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/0.10-stable/src/model/encoding/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js#L162) to determine how to split html to blocks.

**Draft-js 0.10.0**

`div` is aliased with `p` [by default](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/0.10-stable/src/model/immutable/DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap.js#L65) in draft-js@0.10.0